# Flutter: How to align on start and center in Flutter Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want create this layout
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaGzc.png)

4 buttons align to left and Text and edit button align to center
so in web there will be some space

I tried flexible with FlexFit but did not get result as i want (text and edit buton in middle)

EDIT:
I manage to "hack" bad solution
[expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io2Hd.png)

but this cause overflowed warning

```
        Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => Get.offAllNamed(Verifications.ENDPOINT),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                  ...buildNavButtons(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(
              flex: 99,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                GetBuilder<VerificationState>(builder: (_) {
                  return Text(_.verifications[verificationId]!.name);
                }),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
              ],
            ),
            const Spacer(
              flex: 99,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

EDIT 2:
use Stack widget code example in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to use Stack widget

```
Stack(
    children: [
        Row(
            children: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Get.offAllNamed(Verifications.ENDPOINT),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
            ...buildNavButtons(),
            ],
        ),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            GetBuilder<VerificationState>(builder: (_) {
                return Text(_.verifications[verificationId]!.name);
            }),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
            ],
        )
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you should use `Expanded`. It fills the remaining space in a `Row`/`Column` :

```
Row(
    children: [
        Button(),
        Button(),
        Button(),
        Expanded(
            child: Center(
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                        Text(),
                        Button(),
                    ]),
            )
        ),
),
```

Comment: result https://imgur.com/0MTyVUZ
i need text and edit button to be in middle of screen

Answer (score 0):

To create this layout you will require a  row with 3 expanded widgets

```dart
Row(
  children :[
     Expanded(flex: 4, fit: FlexFit.tight,
       child: Row(
         //All 4 buttons here
       )
     ),
     Expanded(flex: 4, fit: FlexFit.tight,
       child: Center(
         //Text with icon here
       )
     ),
     Expanded(flex: 4, fit: FlexFit.tight,
       child: Container()
     ),
   ]
)
```

Comment: this is result https://imgur.com/OQEBqzc
i need that text and edit to be in middle of screen